# c# What happen if span<T>(memory<T>) refers to buffers on stack

Tags: c#, memory, stack-overflow, .net-standard

.NET Standard 2.1 has introduced a new feature where you can "control" the memory blocks instead of copying them: [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-2.1) or [Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=netcore-2.1).

In the docs example, I noticed that it is possible to refer to a stack buffer:

```
byte data = 0;
Span<byte> stackSpan = stackalloc byte[100];
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < stackSpan.Length; ctr++)
   stackSpan[ctr] = data++;
```

As far as I know, stack memory for a process is limited (1MB or 4MB), and we cannot manually release it.

So I guess creating a `Memory<T>` or `Span<T>` will somehow "Pin" the memory location on stack thus we can index it? But wouldn't that be a potenial case of stack-leak which might result in stack-overfolow?
Since the array on stack should live as long as `Memory<T>` or `Span<T>`.

Comment: Yes if you allocate too much memory on the stack it will cause a stack overflow, but the mechanism to allocate an array on the stack (stackalloc) is not new. It has been in C# since the beginning and requires the unsafe keyword to use. Besides there are other much more common ways to cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @MikeZboray Maybe I didn't describe clearly. I mean a "stack leak"

Comment: No.  Creating a pointer to stackalloc memory is always valid, does not require pinning (the stack doesn't move) and does not increase allocation size.  The only thing you'd have to worry about is not using the span beyond the lifetime of the allocation.  The end of the method.  No problem here, the span does not survive it either.

Comment: @HansPassant But how about Memory<T>, it can be a field of a class. In order to be able to access the data via index. The data on stack should survive as long as Memory<T> object survive.Just like the example, it should be valid untill GC kill Memory<T> instance. Am I right?

Comment: What is a "stack leak"? You seem to be under the impression that a reference to a stack allocated array can some how escape to the heap. That is not my understanding of the functionality. `Span<T>` can refer to underlying memory that is on the stack or the heap, but it must live on the stack. `Memory<T>` can refer to memory that is only on the heap. It is itself a normal struct so it does not require an allocation, but is not tied to the stack like `Span<T>` is. `Memory<T>` is similar to `ArraySegment<T>`. See [Stephen Toub's article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx).

Comment: @MikeZboray What I mean is the timing of releasing that data relys on the timing GC kill Memory<T>. If Memory<T> keep exsitence, the data on stack cannot be released. If you save Memory<T> in, for instance, a dependancy property, it will not be GC at all.

Comment: In any scenario where using Memory is *required*, using stackalloc is indeed unwise.  That was already the case before, having it compile first is the major obstacle.  Stuff like async and iterators are not allowed to be unsafe.

Comment: @MikeZboray I didn't see that Memory<T> can only refer to heap. It can refer to T[]. It is true that Memroy<T> itself stays on heap. Now I understand...It should be memtioned on docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is safe as Span's lifetime will be same or shorter than stack-allocated array.

You can't assign result of `stackalloc` to `Memory<T>` at least directly (I don't think even unsafe code can help - [C#: convert generic pointer to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985646/c-convert-generic-pointer-to-array)) so scoping this to just `Span<T>`.

According to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-2.1) you've posted Span lifetime is tied to scope it defined:

> `Span<T>` is a ref struct that is allocated on the stack rather than on the managed heap. Ref struct types have a number of restrictions to ensure that they cannot be promoted to the managed heap,

Note that `ref struct` makes some operations prohibited including the one you should be concerned about - returning `Span<T>` from method where stack was allocated. As result span will be destroyed at the same time (or earlier) then stack frame which included array created by `stackalloc`.

```
   static Span<byte> MySpan()
   {
        Span<byte> span = stackalloc byte[100];
        // error CS8352: Cannot use local 'span' in this context because it may 
        // expose referenced variables outside of their declaration scope
        return span;
    }
```

This also covered in MSDN Magazine article (January 2018) [C# - All About Span: Exploring a New .NET Mainstay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) by Stephen Toub.

Comment: ummm...But you can return Span<T> if it is send in as a parameter? Looks like the compiler does some special treatment to Span<T>

Comment: @joe returning method's parameters does not extend lifetime of those parameter as caller method  must be on the stack (and hence keeping allocated data) till synchronous method returns (you can't use `Span` as async method's parameter for exactly this reason - it "releases" stack of calling method). As result you see different behavior when you try returning `Span` *created* in the method.

Comment: @joe my understanding that "special treatment" is for broader `ref struct` rather than directly for `Span<T>`, but there is definitely plenty of checks added according to specification.